# Find a pattern in a Matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have this 25x25 matrix called 'a' which contains 1s and 0s and I need to the total number of specific patterns in it.

```
    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25
1   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9   0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
12  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
13  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
14  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
15  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
16  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
17  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
18  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
19  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
21  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
22  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
23  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
24  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
25  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

An example of a pattern I need to find is a left2tile pattern:

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    1    0
```

Or a right2tile pattern:

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    1
```

Anyone have any advice on how to solve this?

Comment: This might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31330196/3358272 (translating its use of `data.frame` to your `matrix`). (Actually ... what you first showed here is a `data.frame`, not a `matrix` ... I think; the row names look frame-y and not matrix-y.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute-force method.

Assuming a `matrix`:

```r
str(a)
#  int [1:25, 1:25] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ : chr [1:25] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
#   ..$ : chr [1:25] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...

head(matches <- which(a == left2tile[1,1], arr.ind = TRUE))
#    row col
# 9    9   5
# 10  10   5
# 11  11   5
# 12  12   5
# 13  13   5
# 14  14   5

nrow(matches)
# [1] 55
```

This says that there are 55 matches for the top-left element of `left2tile` within `a`, which is just a start. The first one is as `[9,5]`, second (column-wise) is `[10,5]`, etc.

From here:

```r
matches2 <- Map(function(i,j) a[i+0:1,j+0:1], matches[,1], matches[,2])
head(matches2, 3)
# $`9`
#    V5 V6
# 9   1  1
# 10  1  0
# $`10`
#    V5 V6
# 10  1  0
# 11  1  0
# $`11`
#    V5 V6
# 11  1  0
# 12  1  0
```

Here, we have the first three submatrices of the matches. We can then test for equality:

```r
(matches3 <- sapply(matches2, function(z) all(z == left2tile)))
#     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17     8     9    17    18     7     8    18    19     6     7    19 
# FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
#     6     7    19     6     7    19     6     7    19     6     7    18    19     7     8    17    18     8    15    16 
# FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
#    17     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    17    18    19    19 
# FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Where a `TRUE` indicates that that element within `matches` *does* contain the submatrix match. We can use

```r
matches[matches3,]
#    row col
# 10  10   5
# 11  11   5
# 12  12   5
# 13  13   5
# 14  14   5
# 15  15   5
# 8    8  15
# 9    9  15
# 10  10  15
# 11  11  15
# 12  12  15
# 13  13  15
# 14  14  15
# 15  15  15
# 17  17  16
```

to give us the top-left of each submatrix within `a` that matches `left2tile`.

I would expect (and it is true here) that all of `matches2[matches3]` are the same as your `left2tile`.